# JavaScript file doesn't effect new file imported via jquery load() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a file index.php and there is a main js script in its header.
I'm using Jquery load method to load other php file inside a div element:

```
$("#formHideinAjax").load('loginpass.php');
```

And as our friend explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544662/javascript-not-working-in-jquery-load) the main js file which had loaded in the header doesn't work in new imported file so I was forced to add the js file inside the loginpass.php too(Now I have two same js file, one in header and one in div that loads loginpass.php ! )
I know that this method of loading js file is not standard and sends more request to my server.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is explicitly said in `$.load()` documentation. I'm afraid you can't just paste `<script></script>` code into your DOM for browser to run it.

I'm afraid you have to send JavaScript code from your `loginpass.php` file (without `<script></script>` tags) and just eval it in your JavaScript

```
$("#formHideinAjax").load('loginpass.php', function () {
    // eval JavaScript code from php file here
});
```

Comment: Hi @Danon and Thanks for your reply. I'm going to use this snippet and I will share the result.

Comment: I just changed my loading method like your snippet and it works great now! I Appropriate your help .